# Ping Pong Winning Probability (World Series)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You are playing ping pong with a friend and your chance to win any point is P. This is a world series.

Find the probability that you score 4 points before your friend has a score of 4. Evaluate this expressions for $P=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Standard application of the Negative Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let us imagine we modify the series as follows: Whatever happens, we play $7$ games.

Then you win the original series if and only if you win $4$ **or more** games in the modified series. This may be a familiar problem (binomial distribution).

Comment: Then would this be the proper application?

$P^4 [1+{3 \choose 1}(1-P)+ {4 \choose 3} (1-P)^2 ] $

Comment: Under my suggested approach, we get $\binom{7}{4}p^4(1-p)^3+\binom{7}{5}p^5(1-p)^2+\binom{7}{6}p^6(1-p)+\binom{7}{7}p^7$. The negative binomial approach gives another expression, which looks different but is equivalent.