# Best of seven series in ping pong. Finding probability.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You are playing ping pong with a friend and your chance to win any point is $P$. This is a world series.

Find the probability that you score 4 points before your friend has a score of 4. Evaluate this expressions for $P=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P=\frac{2}{3}$.

I looked at this link: [Ping Pong Winning Probability (World Series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753775/ping-pong-winning-probability-world-series) but the answers nor the comments made any sense to me.

If someone can help me understand how to solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like the slightly sneaky approach taken in the linked answer, we can break the problem into cases. It is clear that there will be either $4$ games in total, or $5$, or $6$, or $7$. We find the associated probabilities, and add them. We will assume independence.

(i) The series lasts $4$ games, and you win: So you win $4$ games in a row. The probability of this is $p^4$.

(ii) The series lasts $5$ games, and you win:  So you win exactly $3$ of the first $4$ games, and win the fifth game. The probability you win $3$ of the first $4$ games is $\binom{4}{3}p^3(1-p)$. If that happens, you have probability $p$ of winning the fifth game. So the probability the series lasts $5$ games and you win is $\binom{4}{3}p^3(1-p)p$.

(iii) The series lasts $6$ games, and you win:  So you win exactly $3$ of the first $5$ games, and win the sixth game. The probability you win $3$ of the first $5$ games is $\binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2$. So the probability the series lasts $6$ games and you win is $\binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2p$.

(iv) The series lasts $7$ games, and you win:  Using the same technique, we find that the probability the series lasts $7$ games and you win is $\binom{6}{3}p^3(1-p)^3p$.

Add up and simplify a little. We get $p^4\left(1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+(1-p)^3\right)$. By summing the short geometric series, we get the somewhat simpler expression $p^3\left(1-(1-p)^4\right)$.

Comment: The probability that we win a game is $p$, and that we lose is $1-p$. Let's find the probability the series lasts $5$ games and we win. This can happen in the following ways. WWWLW, WWLWW, WLWWW, and LWWWW. The probability of WWWLW is $(p)(p)(1-p)(p)$. The probability of WWLWW  is $(p)(p)(1-p)(p)(p)$, the same. Total of $4$ terms, each with probability $p^4(1-p)$, so the probability we win in $5$ games is $4p^4(1-p)$.

Comment: You are welcome. For win in $6$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{5}{3}=10$ gives the number of ways we can choose the $3$ games out of the first $5$ that we win.